# PHP Form Not Showing Full Information on Submission

Tags: php, forms

I have a very simple form from a template with just three fields - Name - Email - Phone. When submitted the form works. BUT - if in the name field you have two words, e.g, John Smith - then it still submits but then everything after the first word gets truncated - so for the example, the mail received would show only "john" and not show "smith", neither will it show email or phone values. I have given my code samples below.. any help is highly appreciated.

PHP CODE BELOW

```
<?php 
$to = 'x@gmail.com, y@gmail.com' ; // Put in your email address here
$subject  = "Appointment Request"; // The default subject. Will appear by   default in all messages. Change this if you want.

// User info (DO NOT EDIT!)
$name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']); // sender's name
$email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']); // sender's email
$phone = stripslashes($_REQUEST['phone']); 

// The message you will receive in your mailbox
// Each parts are commented to help you understand what it does exaclty.
// YOU DON'T NEED TO EDIT IT BELOW BUT IF YOU DO, DO IT WITH CAUTION!
$msg  = "Name: ".$name."\r\n";  // add sender's name to the message
$msg .= "E-mail: ".$email."\r\n";  // add sender's email to the message
$msg .= "Phone: ".$phone."\r\n";  // add sender's email to the message
$msg .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n\n"; // add subject to the message (optional! It will be displayed in the header anyway)
$msg .= "---Message--- \r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n\n"; 

$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From:".$email);  // This command sends the e-mail to the e-mail address contained in the $to variable

if($mail) {
echo 'Your message has been sent, we will be in touch shortly!';  //This is the message that will be shown when the message is successfully send

} else {
echo 'Message could not be sent!';   //This is the message that will be shown when an error occured: the message was not send
}

?>
```

HTML FORM CODE

```
<form role="form" onSubmit="return send_email();">

<div class="form-group">

<label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-mail</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_phone" placeholder="Phone">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-orange btn-Submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'formsubmit', 'lp form', 'LP form');">Book my Free Consultation</button>
        <small id="mail_msg"></small>
      </form>
```

send_email() is actually in a JS file in a separate JS folder.. I have pasted the code below..

JS send_email

```
function send_email() {
var name=$("#app_name").val();
var email=$("#app_email").val();
var phone=$("#app_phone").val();
if(name=="")
{
$("#app_name").addClass("errors");
}
else
{
$("#app_name").removeClass("errors");
}
if(!validEmail(email))
{
$("#app_email").addClass("errors");
}
else
{
$("#app_email").removeClass("errors");
}
if(phone=="")
{
$("#app_phone").addClass("errors");
}
else
{
$("#app_phone").removeClass("errors");
}

if(name!="" && phone!="" && validEmail(email) )
{
$("#mail_msg").load("email.php?name="+name+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone);
$("#app_name").val('');
$("#app_email").val('');
$("#app_phone").val('');
}   
return false;
}
function validEmail(e) {
var filter = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
return String(e).search (filter) != -1;
}
```

Comment: What does `send_email()` do?

Comment: Show send_email () function

Comment: @chris85 tagging as I have posted the code you requested

Comment: @CoderSam tagging as I have posted teh code you requested

Comment: Whats `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` give?

Comment: @chris85 - not sure about that... am not a developer, am using an off the shelf template. I don't see that code snippet you mentioned anywhere in the code..

Comment: You add it to the code

Comment: @chris85   Thanks so much for your patience and help. 
I tried adding the code in the php file -     `var_dump($_SERVER['$name']); `   

after the section..
    `// User info (DO NOT EDIT!)
    $name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']); // sender's name
    $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']); // sender's email
    $phone = stripslashes($_REQUEST['phone']);`

and the response I am getting is - NULL Your message has been sent, we will be in touch shortly!

Comment: I also tried adding it just before `$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From:".$email);  // This command sends the e-mail to the e-mail address contained in the $to variable`    - and it still gives the same response.

Comment: Okay, what about `print_r($_GET);`?